# Want to assing std::string but compiler thinks is bool

Tags: c++, string, methods, std, assign

I pretend to write a class which can act as a variant type.
Everything is working fine, but when I try to assing a string, the method that gets called is the one with bool as a parameter:

```
class value_t {
public:
    value_t operator=(const int& integer) {
        std::cout<<"integer"<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    };
    value_t operator=(const std::string& str) {
        std::cout<<"string"<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    };
    value_t operator=(const bool& boolean) {
        std::cout<<"boolean"<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    };

};

value_t val;
val = "Hola mundo";
```

And the output is:

```
boolean
```

Why is not the string assign operator method get called?

Thank you

Comment: Because `"Hola mundo"` isn't a `std::string`.

Comment: It is what I thought first, but with “(const char* str)” wasn’t working either. And I created a constructor method with std::string as parameter, and the compiler recognized it as a std::string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal like `"Hola mundo"` is a `const char []`, which decays to `const char *`.

The language standard defines an implicit conversion from any pointer to a `bool`.

The compiler chooses your `bool` operator as a better choice because calling your `std::string` operator would require the compiler to construct a temporary `std::string` object, while calling the `bool` operator does not.

To do what you want, add another operator for `const char *` so the compiler doesn't have to convert at all (it can optionally call the `std::string` operator if desired):

```
value_t operator=(const char* str) {
    std::cout << "char*" << std::endl;
    return *this;
};
```

```
value_t operator=(const char* str) {
    return operator=(std::string(str));
};
```

Otherwise, you have to pass in a `std::string` explicitly:

```
val = std::string("Hola mundo");
```

On a side note, your operators should be returning a `value_t&` reference instead.

Comment: Thank you. The duplicated question given by Praetorian and your answer were both right. I googled before answering, and didn’t find it. By the other way, sure I did a mistake when I ve tried (char* str) constructor method...because now is working perfectly. Thank you all.